# How to set locale so language reply headers are in de-DE

Tags: gmail, localization

How can I set up Gmail and set the language such that replies to emails set the correct language of the reply headers to that set locale/language?

So, instead of English I want German to show up:

```
-------- Original Message --------
From: sam@email.com
Sent: Thursday, December 16, 2010 9:33 AM
To: bob@email.com
Subject: Good morning!
```

...to this (in the case of German):

```
-----Ursprüngliche Nachricht-----
Von: sam@email.com
Gesendet: Donnerstag, 16. Dezember 2010 09:33
An: bob@email.com
Betreff: Good morning!
```

Comment: I see "Language" as the very first option under `Settings > General`. Does that not work?

Comment: @AlE. it sets the language for the ide but not for the string literal reply headers (when replying to a msg the headers stay in english regardless of what he language is set to).  other email clients like thunderbird honor if the language is set say de-de the email reply headers are set to the same language (de-de) and not defaulting to en-us.

Comment: It's very likely that you can't change that, then. Certainly there's nothing in Gmail settings about changing the language of message headers.

Comment: thx for the reply.  the odd thing is if I used my iphone7 and download the gmail app and set my language on the device to de-de i get translated email reply headers (i.e. they are in german...from/to/sent/date/subject/etc).  I guess that's what you get with interns and other groups developing mobile vs client apps.  :)

Answer (score 1):

As of 2017-01-23, `Settings > General > Language > Gmail display language` seems to work.
However, I tested it by forwarding, not by replying, as you needed. Reply formatting seems to be now very bare, not the standard header.
Thanks @ale for hint